# English version of E. B. Dynkin, русский version “Semisimple subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras”

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams, mathematical-russian

I was recommended to consult a mathematical text:

E. B. Dynkin, “Semisimple subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras”, Mat. Sb. (N.S.), 30(72):2 (1952), 349–462.

But I find that the paper is written in Russian русский:
http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=5435&option_lang=eng
http://www.mathnet.ru/links/83b544bbde2b8abefdb3d6ede25dcb92/sm5435.pdf

Do we know any English translation of the original paper? Thank you - please provide the English version link.

Comment: It appears in Dynkin's selected papers, published by the AMS. You should be able to see it on Google Books. Around p.220.

Comment: The AMS version is better than the original paper, because it reports also on misprints and errors by Dynkin. And there are several typos in these 220 pages.

Comment: thanks +1 for comments

Answer (score 4):

The paper was translated into English in [American Mathematical Society Translations: Series 2, Volume 6, 1957](https://www.ams.org/books/trans2/006/) DOI:[10.1090/trans2/006](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/trans2/006) You should check your local libraries for journal holdings. Most math departments would have collected this journal. Here is a very partial find in a [library](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/1097160348) mostly reporting libraries which have only a few volumes of this journal (including the desired volume).

Since 2000, it is also available in Dynkin's [Selected Papers](https://bookstore.ams.org/cworks-14) MR[1757976](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1757976) Find in a [library](https://www.worldcat.org/title/selected-papers-of-eb-dynkin-with-commentary/oclc/41540287). The paper begins on page 175.

Comment: thanks +1. Is the PDF file freely available in one of the link?

Comment: I did not see a free and legal PDF file (unless your institution is some sort of Gold level AMS member), but the paper is 130 pages long with lots of tables. I have often found paper versions of such things to be easier to read (especially when tables span multiple pages). The book is pretty commonly held in libraries -- you might check your local library. He has a few other highly cited papers as well in there.